# Javascript Regex array of matches not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using the javascript match() function as follows

```
var str = "100% Scored"; 
var reg = "/\b(10|sales|100%)\b/i"
var res = str.match(reg);
```

But `res` is not getting '100%' value.  I tried changing the regex many ways but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal with `/…/`, like this:

```
var reg = /\b(10|sales|100%)\b/i;
```

Note however, that `\b` will only match a position between 'word' characters, and `%` is not a word character, so this will not match the `"100% Scored"`

Try this pattern:

```
var str = "100% Scored"; 
var reg = /\b(10|sales|100%)(?!\w)/i;
var res = str.match(reg);
console.log(res);         // [ "100%", "100%" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern for taking out X% or XX% or XXX%:

```
var str = "100% Scored"; 
var reg = "^[0-9]{1,3}%"
var res = str.match(reg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Regex

```
var reg = /\b(10|sales|100%)(?!\w)/i;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLHJ5/1/)

Comment: `Regex` should not be in a code span, it is not code.